# Eclipse: how to avoid blocking user input of frequent saves with build on save enabled?

Tags: eclipse

I have activated an option "Build on resource save". My typing habits is to save the code every few seconds and whenever previous build is not complete before I save again, I get a window like this:

[image: User Operation is Waiting]

Basically Eclipse is forcing me to wait before it will finish the previous build and start a new one. Can I somehow configure it, so that it will start new build automatically once the previous is completed and will not block my input? It is okay if it will incorporate multiple consequent saves of the code.

Comment: You can run eclipse processes in the background right?

Comment: @SRy: It does run in background for the first build, but when I save it second time - it tries to stop me making further changes and thus blocks my input with a popup.

Comment: How can Eclipse build something when you're still making changes? Why you need to "build on resource save"?

Comment: It can build the last version. I need build on resource save to save time... it starts building automatically while I am switching windows to start an app (I need another tool for that because it's a managed app using some unmanaged code).

Comment: This sort of thing can get pretty complicated pretty fast, depending on what you wish to accomplish.  Are the build tasks long relative to "a few seconds"?  Do you need to operate on a "snapshot" of the data that exists when you want to submit the build task (or just whatever data exists when the build actually starts)?  Can your project tolerate changes to the data as the build is happening?  The problem sounds like it should suggest a producer-consumer queue for tasks, but the solution could be really complex depending on your needs.

Comment: why do you need to build on save? it sounds like you are not doing anything with the build right away anyways (if you are continuing to do work and make more changes/saves/builds), so why not just build when you want to build?

Comment: @invertigo: this was my solution in the end. i just wanted Eclipse to have a fresh build for me while I'm thinking, but don't get in a way while I am actually typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, my solution was not to build on save. As scottb mentioned in comments it is too complicated to actually decide when it is save to build and when it is not.